# Pandas dataframe mixed data

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

So i imported data in pandas using url and it was a jason file however my data is appearing like

Index    Column
{‘company’:”, ‘accounting’:’xxxx’, ‘title’:’xxxx’}

However all these data are appearing under one column name so i want to properly format in a tabular format and assigning different column name to each one

1. Index|column a|column b|
   0.  | Company |accounting

Comment: Pls post a real sample of your data